# What can cause a postback to not be routed to the handler

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity-4

I have a user control that worked fine in a plain ASP.NET web application, but now that I've converted it to a Sitefinity Module, it is not functioning. Specifically, when I click an asp:LinkButton that has an OnClick handler, the handler is never being called. A postback DOES occur, though - if I set a breakpoint in Page_Load, it get's hit. But the handler itself is never called.

Has anyone else ever run into this? Any ideas on what might be interfering with the event stack?

Answer (score 0):

in the Page settings, make sure that "Enable Viewstate" is checked. by default, Sitefinity disables Viewstate in pages and that will usually cause postbacks to fail.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Do you mean within Sitefinity? Our page's template is based on a ASP.NET Master Page, which has the view state enabled. Do we need to enable it within Sitefinity as well?

Comment: yes, when you create a page in Sitefinity, and select your template, there is an option below to enable viewstate. by default it is disabled. open your page properties (under the Actions menu on the Page list) and check the box. hopefully this should do it!